# How to use Colorbox with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, colorbox

How can I use colorbox (fancybox or lightbox is welcome too) with Angular JS, should I write a directive for it is there any other methods for it.

Here is my HTML:

```
...
<h2 class="box-header">
    <i class="icon-hdd"></i>    
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">      
        <a class="btn btn-mini">
            <i class="icon-zoom-in"></i>
            Expand
        </a>
    </div>
</h2>   
<div id="open-with-colorbox">
...
</div>
...
```

User will click expand button and div that has open-with-colorbox id will open as colorbox.

**PS:** I am new to Angular JS that's why I am looking for a solution how to use colorbox, I use twitter bootstrap at my application.

Comment: How to call below from controller. isn't it possible to call from controller. I am very new to angularjs. It's saying colorbox is not a function. I have included all js,css files.
                $.colorbox({
                    iframe: true,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    href: "http://" + result,
                })

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Write a directive, it's the best option.

Directive example:

```
app.directive('colorbox', function() {
  return {   
    restrict: 'AC',    
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {        
      $(element).colorbox(attrs.colorbox);     
    }
  };  
});
```

HTML:

```
<a colorbox="{transition:'fade'}" href="...">Image</a>
```

Comment: What does restrict means here?

Comment: Restrict refers to the declaration style, `A` is for Attribute and `C` for Class. You can check more information on this [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (search for 'restrict').

Comment: It tries to open it at a new page how can I prevent it?

Comment: Are you sure the directive is being loaded? Opening on a new page is the default `<a></a>` behaviour, which should be automatically prevented if the directive was being applied. Try to debug and check if the line `$(element).colorbox(attrs.colorbox);` is being invoked.

Comment: How do you make multiple pictures relative to each other?
I tried to put the an unique id on the attribute but the attribute comes as undefined on the body of the directive.

Comment: Found out: attr.$observe('attr_name', function(value){ //handle here })

Comment: @bmleite expanding upon what you showed here ... is this proper syntax: `<a colorbox="{transition:'fade', html:'<p>Hello</p>'}">Image</a>`

Comment: @pulkitsinghal it only seems to be missing the `href`, the rest seems to be correct.

Comment: I had a problem using this example that stemmed from the fact that attrs.colorbox is being passed into the colorbox function as a string and not as an object. Changing it to `JSON.parse(attrs.colorbox)` and changing the HTML to `<a colorbox='{"transition":"fade"}' href="...">Image</a>` fixed it though.

Comment: @Andrew, `scope.$eval(attrs.colorbox)` is a better alternative to JSON.parse in this case

Answer (score 3):

I have tried bmleite directive in my code but it doesnt work. The cboxElement class added to the element but colorbox didnt open when clicked. Finally i found this directive which worked like a charm.

```
app.directive('colorbox', function($compile, $rootScope){
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.click('bind', function(){
        $.colorbox({
          href: attrs.colorbox,
          onComplete: function(){
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
              var content = $('#cboxLoadedContent');
              $compile(content)($rootScope);      
            })
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then in your html section use it with:

```
<img src="path_to_image" colorbox="path_to_large_image" />
```