# ColorBox with AngularJS, with ng-click bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ok, so it's fairly easy to create a directive for a colorbox, as explained here:

[How to use Colorbox with Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641791/how-to-use-colorbox-with-angular-js)

But what if you want to then bind buttons to ng-click events? Best practice would suggest that the handler function for the action (delete in my case) should be in a directive defined on the controller. My colorbox directive looks like this:

```
    mod.directive('colorbox', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            controller: function($scope, $element){
                $scope.delete = function() {
                    console.log('I want this code to fire');
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).colorbox({ inline: true, title: ' ', href: "#delconfirm", className: "delgroup", width: 450, height: 200, close: "" }, function() {
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

My template that will be loaded into the colorbox contains an action button with an `ng-click`:

```
            <button ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
```

However, that doesn't work. IF I move that delete function to my parent controller instead, and remove the controller from the directive, it then works. Any ideas why?

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with color box/jQuery- since JQuery and Angular don't always play nice.  Here's a fiddle with what you describe working, just without color box:  http://jsfiddle.net/5BkpN/

Comment: You may want to encapsulate the jQuery within a directive like you did but then create a second outer directive that adds your buttons and includes the jQuery directive.  That way you can isolate jQuery into it's own scope.